# Lilypond: Adjusting position of accidentals of a chord

Tags: lilypond

I'd like to adjust position of accidentals like a right note. How to that?

P.S ) right note is added via MS Paint

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly the ordering of the Accidentals is a bit hardcoded (though technically it would be little effort to add an additional Accidental property to influence order). Currently the placement of Accidentals is done by the `positioning-done` hook of the `AccidentalPlacement` grob, which collects and offsets all concurrent Accidentals at Staff level (https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/internals/accidental_002dplacement_002dinterface). The simplest way would be to disable this (not really necessary, but if we place all Accidentals manually, but if only a single Accidental is not placed manually this would else destroy all manual positioning!) and then manually position the Accidentals:

```
{
  \once\override Staff.AccidentalPlacement.positioning-done = ##f
  <\tweak Accidental.X-offset #-2.48 fis'
   \tweak Accidental.X-offset #-1.45 cis''
   \tweak Accidental.X-offset #-2.48 gis''
   \tweak Accidental.X-offset #-1.45 dis'''>2
}
```

Alternatively one could override the `Staff.AccidentalPlacement.positioning-done` hook.

Comment: Wow... I thought a solution, but your solution is more simple than mine.. Thanks you!

Comment: I used Accidental.X-Offset and Accidental.extra-offset, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pythagorean_comma&diff=1159652689